# wpf selfbinding: binding color to change as the text of the lable changes

Tags: wpf, data-binding, vb.net-2010

i am learning WPF now and created an application. it is working fine in view and code separated.
It extracts details from a web site. list out all the details of the product and their specifications and dump it all in an excel. so far all is good.
now i want to databind the view of giving the look and the progress to the user.
i am able to get the values out from the class and displaying in the label. i want to show how much of each web is loaded by changing the color of the label.
This is the XAML

```
<Window x:Class="WebExtractor.AvnetMainClass"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Avenet_Web_Extractor.WebExtractor"
xmlns:diag="clr-namespace:System.Diagnostics;assembly=WindowsBase"
Title="Avnet Product Details Extractor" 
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" Height="300" Width="538" 
ResizeMode="NoResize">

<Window.Resources>
    <local:ColorConvert x:Key="colorConvert"/>

</Window.Resources>
```

data binding is here

```
<StackPanel Margin="164,4,4,5" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
                    <Label Name="lbl1PrdFll" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Width="312" Height="27" Margin="0,2,0,0" Background="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Caption,Converter={StaticResource colorConvert}}" Content="{Binding Path=prdFrstState, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" ></Label>
                    <Label Name="lbl2PrdFll" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Width="312" Height="27" Margin="0,2,0,0" Background="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Caption,Converter={StaticResource colorConvert}}"  Content="{Binding Path=prdScndState, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></Label>
                    <Label Name="lbl3PrdFll" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Width="312" Height="27" Margin="0,2,0,0" Background="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Caption,Converter={StaticResource colorConvert}}"  Content="{Binding Path=prdLstState, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></Label>
```

vb.net code for color changing is:

```
Namespace WebExtractor

<ValueConversion(GetType(String), GetType(SolidColorBrush))> _
Public Class ColorConvert
    Implements IValueConverter
    Public Function Convert(ByVal value As Object, ByVal targetType As Type, ByVal parameter As Object, ByVal culture As CultureInfo) As Object Implements IValueConverter.Convert
        Dim boundWord As String = TryCast(value, String)
        Dim returnBrush As SolidColorBrush = Nothing
        Select Case boundWord.ToLower().Trim()

            Case "UnInti"
                returnBrush = New SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red)
            Case "Loading"
                returnBrush = New SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red)
            Case "Loaded"
                returnBrush = New SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightPink)
            Case "Interactive"
                returnBrush = New SolidColorBrush(Colors.Pink)
            Case "Complete"
                returnBrush = New SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green)
        End Select

        Return returnBrush
    End Function

    Public Function ConvertBack(ByVal value As Object, ByVal targetType As Type, ByVal parameter As Object, ByVal culture As CultureInfo) As Object Implements IValueConverter.ConvertBack
        Throw New Exception("Cant convert back")
    End Function
End Class
```

End Namespace

is there any option to change the color on fly like "lblprdfrst.background=color.red"

Comment: which part doesnt work?  did you try using snoop?

Comment: Ya. i did. it told the binding of the caption is error. "unable to find  such path" i changed it to content. still showing same error. i am able to do it in text box

Comment: I am trying to change the color of the lables as the loading of web page changes

Comment: Label control doesnt have Caption path

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the background property directly to a property on your view model as suggested by makc, or if you are changing the colour based on known fixed rules, you can do this using data triggers, that trigger based on the value of your boundword variable.
Here's a tutorial site with examples for data triggers http://zamjad.wordpress.com/2009/08/21/data-trigger-in-wpf/